# How to open a file from python with the name only?

Tags: python-2.7

I know that this question may be silly, and I am OK with that since I am at a rookie level. 
I would like to know whether there is a way to open a file in python by entering only its name , e.g `open(mbox.txt)` instead of `open(C:\Python27\mbox.txt)`??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know whether there is a way to open a file in python
>   by entering only its name

You can open a file without providing the `path`, as long as the file is **located on the same** `dir` as the python script.

Comment: This isn't quite right. The file needs to be in the current working directory, which may or may not be the location of the script, depending on how you run it. You can find the current working directory by calling `os.getcwd`, and you can change it by calling `os.chdir`.

Comment: You're right, but we need to adapt the answer to the OP, in this case, I guess my answer is clear.

Comment: When I enter import os and then os.getcwd it shows <built-in function getcwd> but does not tell me anything about a directory, is that te proper way to call the os.getcwd??

Comment: My scrip is located at C:\Python27 and the file is located at C:\Python27 as well, however, when I run the script it shows the following error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\Open.py", line 1, in <module>
    fhand = open('romeo.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'romeo.txt'

Comment: @L.Gonzalez: You need to call the function: `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @Blckknght thanks a lot, I have now called os.getcwd() and it gave me this result: 'C:\\Python27' , which means that would be my working directory. My script and file are in working directory, but I keep getting the error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\python27\Open.py", line 1, in <module> fhand = open('romeo.txt') IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'romeo.txt'

Answer (score 1):

Python looks for file you mention, without their complete path, in the following directories listed in `sys.path`

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
     print path
```

you will get the list of directories in which the python looks for, if you would specify a file in a different directory than this list, just add the directory name into this and you can specify files in them without complete path.

**Correction**

The above suggestion does not answer the question, as Jon said it only affects import machinery. To answer your question, change the directory using os module of the python.

```
import os
os.chdir('to_the_respective_directory')
open('file.txt')
```

Comment: This applies to the import machinery in Python - not to how the builtin `open` works.